# Toggle proxy settings based on the wired/wireless connection you make

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, automation

Without using third party software, is there a way to have Windows toggle your proxy settings on/off based on the wired/wireless connection you make?

I'm aware that I could create a registry script and run that each time to toggle the proxy settings but I'm more interested in something that would automatically trigger the proxy settings to change based on when a wired/wireless network connection was established.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try creating a `proxy.pac` file.  Depending if you know both addresses (wired and wireless) you could try this:

> function FindProxyForURL(url, host) 
>   { 
>    if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "192.168.1.0", "255.255.255.0")) // Wired connection
>     return "PROXY 192.168.1.1:8080"; 
>    if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "192.168.2.0", "255.255.255.0")) // Wireless connection
>     return "PROXY 192.168.2.1:8080"; 
>    else 
>     return "DIRECT"; 
>   }

Then just point the browser to where you saved the proxy.pac file for the automatic configuration script.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Proxypal](http://www.bartdart.com) should work and there are a few [Firefox extensions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=switch+proxy) too.